# How to specify relative path for image in xsl

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am using following xsl to display icons

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="html"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <img src="file:///c:/view.png" alt=""/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With absolute path, this works, when we specify absolute path along with "file:///", but when we use relative path like "file:///./icon/view.png", it is not working (no image is getting displayed in html). Required Icons are located in subfolder "icons" of xml located folder. For. ex. xml folder location is "C:\1\2\3\4\result.xml" and icons are located at "C:\1\2\3\4\icons". How to specify relative path to access images under icons folder. Tried "file:///../icons/view.png" but no success.
Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I tried below transformation:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="html"/> <xsl:template match="/"> <html>
<img><xsl:attribute name="src">./icons/EQ1.png</xsl:attribute></img>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and get the output as:

```
<html><img src="./icons/EQ1.png"></html>
```

Also I placed EQ1.png in the icons folder which is placed at my html file's folder itself. I viewed HTML in Firefox and can able to view the image.

Comment: I tried <img src="file:///./icon/new.png"/>" alt="MM"/>, but no success. I am able to see images successfully only if i use "file:///" along with absolute path. like "<img src="file:///C:/1/2/3/4/icons/new.png"/>" alt="MM"/>. Even if I use only absoulte path without using "file:///", then also there wont be any image output.

Comment: Tried following:  
<img alt=""><xsl:attribute name="src">./icons/view.png</xsl:attribute></img>

<img alt=""><xsl:attribute name="src">../icons/view.png</xsl:attribute></img>

<img alt=""><xsl:attribute name="src">file:///./icons/view.png</xsl:attribute></img>

<img alt=""><xsl:attribute name="src">file:///../icons/view.png</xsl:attribute></img>

<img alt=""><xsl:attribute name="src">file:///~/icon/new.png</xsl:attribute></img> but no sucess. 
only this is working
<img alt=""><xsl:attribute name="src">file:///C:/1/2/3/4/icons/new.png</xsl:attribute></img>

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried your code and it worked, might be it was issue with browser settings.